# XCode build phases: run script in background (without blocking build)

Tags: xcode

I'd like to be able to run a script in the background (i.e. without blocking the build process) when I build and run an iOS application in the simulator. I've tried `osascript /path/to/script &`, and also backgrounding a separate shell script that does the same, but neither have worked; the build stops and I have to force quit XCode.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any luck with this? I was hoping that you you just append `&` to the end of your command, but it doesn't look like that works.

Comment: Sadly no. I have just been running the background script when I need it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same trouble with running a background script as part of the build phase but the following does work in my case. The script runs in the background while my app runs. Apparently, you have to redirect the standard output in addition to using the "&". Use the following format. (My script is located in directory '~/Desktop/splint_server/')

```
~/Desktop/splint_server/run.sh > ~/Desktop/splint_server/test 2>&1 &
```

This runs an arbitrary script at `~/Desktop/splint_server/run.sh` (put the path to your script there). The output is redirected to a log file called "test".

More information about I/O redirection http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: If you don't care about your script's output `~/Desktop/splint_server/run.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &` works as well.

Comment: This is not correct for XCode `8.2.1.` anymore, which waits until all spawned processes terminated. You can test this by adding `sleep 200 &` and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Incase you are still interested.

These are the steps you need to follow:
1. Change the .sh extension of your script to .command
2. Rather than invoking /path/to/script.sh you now start using "open /path/to/script.command"

Thats pretty much it.

This will start a new terminal window and run the script you want in it.

Comment: This requires some access priveleges

Answer (score 1):

You could use post-actions of build in the schemes setting.

"sleep 100&" works fine