# CMake add_custom_command run in background

Tags: cmake

I have a command executed in a POST_BUILD step using `add_custom_command()`. It takes quite some time, but I don't need the results to run the executable, I just want it to start after the build. Is there a way to run such a command in the background so that the executable can be run right after the build without waiting for the command to finish?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use some platform-specific logic, one way is to use a shell script to launch the command you want to run in the background. A very crude example for Unix systems may look like this:

*launcher.sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh

"$@"&
```

*CMakeLists.txt*:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET myTarget POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/launcher.sh whateverYouWantToRun
)
```

You could add something equivalent for Windows and then test the [`CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME.html) variable to choose which launcher script to use.

Comment: I already tried this approach with no success. Maybe it's the IDE waiting for all the spawned processes (I tested in XCode and AppCode on mac).

Comment: Yes, thanks to your comment I realized the issue wasn't on CMake side, and I found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028336/xcode-build-phases-run-script-in-background-without-blocking-build